# Over Function in R gives unexpected results

Tags: r, polygon, geospatial, spatial, r-sp

I want to perform an `over` from the `sp` package. 
However, the results I am getting are unexpected. 
My `polygon` overlays with nine Points. However, after the `over()` it only returns 1 point. Why is that?

Here a reproducible example!

```
library(sp)

# The point data
myPoi <- structure(list(index = c(2L, 17L, 19L, 23L, 34L, 71L, 82L, 85L, 
92L, 96L, 102L, 7L, 20L, 29L, 40L, 50L, 100L, 103L, 84L, 91L, 
11L, 61L, 70L, 76L, 45L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 13L, 
14L, 18L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 51L, 52L, 55L, 
56L, 58L, 60L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 68L, 69L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 77L, 
78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 83L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 97L, 
98L, 99L, 101L, 104L, 12L, 15L, 66L, 86L), x = c(13.0165026, 
13.0164516, 13.0164489, 13.0164114, 13.0164328, 13.0162478, 13.016237, 
13.0164516, 13.0160949, 13.0163309, 13.0164597, 13.02528, 13.0159466, 
13.0437784, 13.0309044, 13.0335449, 13.0289418, 13.0253004, 13.0446292, 
13.0434527, 13.0394242, 12.9720291, 13.0315502, 13.0397486, 13.0195456, 
13.036048, 13.0356159, 13.0283043, 13.0178174, 13.0395106, 13.0182921, 
13.0286984, 13.0382137, 13.0389044, 13.035627, 13.0179864, 13.0387113, 
13.0413548, 13.0176216, 13.0395562, 13.0330164, 13.0377135, 13.0410115, 
13.0176398, 13.0183699, 13.0413454, 13.0178389, 13.0373272, 13.0383505, 
13.0331394, 13.0181419, 13.0184316, 13.0415063, 13.0373487, 13.0390412, 
13.0179944, 13.0298012, 13.0358995, 13.041501, 13.0331575, 13.0183914, 
13.0293197, 13.0389486, 13.0176076, 13.0357577, 13.017694, 13.0411228, 
13.0184692, 13.0182787, 13.0184531, 13.0348261, 13.0387716, 13.0377537, 
13.0358131, 13.0332953, 13.0385517, 13.0409887, 13.0360657, 13.0181661, 
13.0411724, 13.0359306, 13.0382338, 13.0383103, 13.0348797, 13.0357777, 
13.043133, 13.0390318, 13.0384913, 13.0412797, 13.0359298, 13.0386354, 
13.0297737, 13.0294306, 13.033415), y = c(52.4009649, 52.4003774, 
52.4004641, 52.40168, 52.4014313, 52.4022691, 52.4024115, 52.4012316, 
52.4024066, 52.4002121, 52.4002186, 52.4011368, 52.4063829, 52.4004306, 
52.408314, 52.4033442, 52.3988618, 52.4036956, 52.403118, 52.4023966, 
52.4001135, 52.4045952, 52.4124868, 52.4040269, 52.4044583, 52.4021688, 
52.4021458, 52.4025064, 52.4020523, 52.4024279, 52.401748, 52.4032264, 
52.4022585, 52.4023951, 52.4020268, 52.400694, 52.4024549, 52.4021521, 
52.4021309, 52.4020433, 52.4025458, 52.4023542, 52.4022225, 52.3996966, 
52.4010574, 52.402468, 52.4005992, 52.4022168, 52.4020114, 52.4024885, 
52.4007988, 52.4011998, 52.402247, 52.4020875, 52.4021521, 52.4019705, 
52.4048047, 52.402235, 52.4023853, 52.4026649, 52.4016137, 52.4048988, 
52.4020327, 52.3999584, 52.402231, 52.4005386, 52.4024549, 52.4013388, 
52.400928, 52.4014714, 52.4013764, 52.4019623, 52.4019729, 52.4017299, 
52.402618, 52.4019558, 52.4023567, 52.4020376, 52.4018642, 52.4021448, 
52.4019606, 52.4021251, 52.4023698, 52.401446, 52.4019525, 52.4011382, 
52.402283, 52.4024483, 52.4020605, 52.4017324, 52.4101571, 52.405268, 
52.4046133, 52.4043887), poi = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("artwork", "attraction", 
"gate", "memorial", "ruins", "statue", "viewpoint"), class = "factor"), 
gewichtung = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L)), .Names = c("index", "x", 
"y", "poi", "gewichtung"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-94L))

# corner of polygon
cornersPoly <- structure(c(13.0302143096924, 13.0232620239258, 13.0237770080566, 
13.0296993255615, 13.0326175689697, 52.4066068887721, 52.4047742038877, 
52.400375449523, 52.3982282791922, 52.4042505656507), .Dim = c(5L, 
2L))
```

And here my code!

```
# make points spatial
coordinates(myPoi) <- ~x + y
proj4string(myPoi) <- CRS("+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs")

# make polygon from matrix
# create Polygon
myPolygon <- Polygon(cornersPoly)

# create Polygon List
myPolygonList <- Polygons(list(myPolygon), 1)

# create spatial Polygon 
myPolygonSpatial <- SpatialPolygons(list(myPolygonList))

# assign CRS
proj4string(myPolygonSpatial) <- CRS("+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs")


# perform the over
test <- over(myPolygonSpatial, myPoi)
```

**edit**

with the comment from Josh O'Brien I get that as a result

> 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
>   25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA
>   NA  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA  1  33 34 35 36 37 38
>   39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61
>   62 63 64  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
>   NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA  65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75
>   76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94  NA NA NA NA
>   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
>   1  1 NA

Comment: I think you actually want `over(myPoi, myPolygonSpatial)` or, alternatively, `rgeos::gWithin(myPoi, myPolygonSpatial, byid=TRUE)` or the like.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien not sure of that is still what I need. I get a `named int` with many numbers and many `NA` in it... See my edit

Comment: That vector does have the info you need, albeit in a slightly awkward format: its non-NA elements correspond precisely to those points that overlap your polygon. Try this, for example, so see that that's so: `overlapPoints <- myPoi[!is.na(test),]`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien thanks mate. awesome.

Comment: You bet. Glad to help. In your case, the elements of the vector are all either `NA` (for points that don't overlap the polygon) or `1` (for points that do). If there were two polygons, and some points overlapped the second one, they would have produce elements with value `2` (to distinguish them from points overlapping the first polygon).   I happen to prefer the grid/matrix format of the results output by `rgeos::gWithin()`, which is why  I mentioned that alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
test <- over(myPolygonSpatial, myPoi, returnList = TRUE)
```

and look at the first element of the list returned. The issue why this looks complicated is that `myPolygonSpatial` may contain multiple points; the list will contain the set of sets of points. Reading `vignette(over)` may also pay off.